# Custom SSL doesn't show when using CloudFlare

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I have certified SSL from godaddy. It works fine and the green address bar with the name of my company shows up when I use it without cloudflare. However when I change my dns to cloudflare and turn SSL Strict mode on, the green lock says I have SSL from cloud flare (it shows a different ssl certificate). I don't know what to do to still show my certified ssl in the address bar.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Server configuration is off-topic.

Comment: @MarcB there are thousands of answered server config questions here. As you can see these tags are available for users to use. it okay thanks for the downvote you must be feeling proud now.

Comment: actually, I hadn't downvoted. but since you insist... have another.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: (For what its worth, I don't think the question was worthy of 4 down votes. I upvoted in an effort to offset them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer incase someone in future is having the same problem:
EV certificates are only supported on paid business or enterprise subscriptions: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170446-Can-I-use-an-EV-or-OV-SSL-certificate-with-CloudFlare-Business-and-Enterprise-only-